# Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the following reasonment correct?

There is a sort of duality between non-decreasing functions and *Borel outer measures*.

In particular, given a non-decreasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the associated *Lebesgue-Stieltjes outer measure* $\lambda_f$ is a *Radon outer measure*.

Viceversa, given $\mu$  finite Borel outer measure measure, the so called *distribution function* associated to $\mu$, $f(x):=\mu((-\infty,x])$, is non-decreasing and right-continuous.

My questions are:

1. If we do not require $\mu$ to be Borel, what will happen to the distribution $f$?
2. If we do not require $\mu$ to be finite, what will happen to the distribution $f$?
3. If we require $\mu$ to be also Radon, what will happen to the distribution $f$?